# getting net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in my extensions requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Here is my fetch function in `background.js`:

```js
async function ajaxCall(type,path , data , datatype, callback) {
        // Default options are marked with *
        url = domain+path;

        const form_data = new URLSearchParams(data);
        if (type === "GET"){
            console.log("TYPE",type);
            options = {
                method: type,
                mode: 'cors',
                credentials: 'include' // include cookies
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("TYPE",type);
            options = {
                method: type, // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                headers: {
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: form_data // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
            }
        }
        await fetch(url, options)
            .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.log(response);
                throw new Error(response);
            }
            try {
                return response.json();
            }
            catch{
                throw new Error(response);
            }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('response: ', response);
                callback(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation', error);
                callback(false);
            });
    }
```

and here is my necessary parts of manifest.json:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "options_page": "views/options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "http://*/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "js/lib/vanillatoasts.js","js/app/content.js"],
      "css": ["css/bootstrap-iso.css", "css/bootstrap-customization.css", "css/vanillatoasts.css", "css/multipleaccountselection.css"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/app/background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "views/popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
    "resources": ["/images/*"],
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my `content.js` script which gets executed when I open a webpage, when I pass message to `background.js` to make a GET request I am getting `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error while when I make same request by clicking on the extension and sending it from `popup.js`, I do not get an error. I use self-signed certificates on my server and I have to visit home page of the server prior to using extension in a new tab and ignore certificate warning to make extension work (which also I couldn't find a solution such as SSL pinning etc). It is also important to mention that `content.js` doesn't throw error when it makes a request immediately after the request is made by popup.js but after sometime passes like 5 seconds it starts throwing same error until I make the same request again by clicking on extension.
[image: network tab of background.js]